# VLOOKUP missing entries?

Tags: vlookup, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a decently sized spreadsheet of about 6 thousand entries and I am trying to match two columns to make sure they match up using `vlookup` and that is working fine but I have about 400 or so entries that don't have a match and looking through a few and just using control-f to see if they were somewhere with a different naming convention I found the a matching cell for several of the entries that supposedly don't have a match, any clue why this might be? I checked the length of the values in the cell to see if there was white spacing I was missing but they matched in length and the values in the cell are the exact same. This is the `vlookup` setup I am using

`=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$6074,1,0)`. The CSV is [here](https://gitlab.com/greenbeast/csv) if anyone wanted to see it. I am not saying they are all wrong but I looked at about 10 or so and they all had matches so I am a bit lost on this.

Comment: Please give examples of some lines out of 10 tested. The first mismatch between ` 067N3160` and `067N3160` is indeed caused by an extra space. But you said that there are strings for exactly the same length?

Comment: By the way, `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$6074;1;0);"")` found 5906 results, `...VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2);$B$2:$B$6074;1;0)...` - 5900 results, `...VLOOKUP(A2;TRIM($B$2:$B$6074);1;0)...` - 3618 results, and
`...VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2);TRIM($B$2:$B$6074)...` - 5913 results. So, just 93 cells from A not matched to column B:  Ball Valve B225, #18 PVC END CAP, #7 PVC 90, #8 PVC SSL 8.0, 2989225281, 2989225469, 2989225473, 2989225835, 3288622820 etc.  For example, `PVC SSL 8.0` present in column B, but without prefix "#8 "

Comment: Sorry, i got distracted. I checked row 2549, 5893, 5898, 5498 5951 and 5956. It is all in column F where I just did the `len` function. Thank you for the `VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2);TRIM($B$2:$B$6074)`, that seems to be the best option so far. I am not used to using spreadsheets and usually just solve this with Pandas for Python but I figured going through this with Calc would be a bit easier.